# Passing NSTextFiels as method argument?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, methods, arguments

So I have a IBOutlet NSSecureTextField called *password, and I'm calling a method with animation on it, when user entered wrong password:

```
- (void)shakeWithStrength:(NSInteger)strength {

CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
animation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithPoint:CGPointMake(password.frame.origin.x-strength, password.frame.origin.y)];
animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithPoint:CGPointMake(password.frame.origin.x+strength, password.frame.origin.y)];

[password.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];
}
```

I want to move this method into it's own separate class, but how can I pass NSSecureTextField (or something else, a button for example) as an argument?

Answer (score 1):

NSView is the super class of NSSecureTextField, NSButton, NSTextField. So you can use NSView as an argument

```
- (void)shakeWithStrength:(NSInteger)strength view:(NSView *)view {

    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    animation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithPoint:CGPointMake(view.frame.origin.x-strength, view.frame.origin.y)];
    animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithPoint:CGPointMake(view.frame.origin.x+strength, view.frame.origin.y)];

    [secureTextField.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but if it is, for example, a button, I would have to go and change NSSecureTextField to NSButton and so on. I was asking is there a way to pass any object as an argument. I tried to pass NSObject or id, but they dont have .layer and .frame, and my method uses that. So I was wondering, should I create CALayer and frame inside of this method?